# Search/Find Panel default text

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, devexpress, tableview

I would really like to change default "Search" text of Search/Find Panel ...

Here is the peace of my code:

```
<dxg:GridControl.View>
<dxg:TableView … ShowSearchPanelMode="Always" SearchPanelFindMode="Always">

                                . . .

</dxg:TableView>
</dxg:GridControl.View>
```

Do I need to override some template and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to override some template and if so, how?

To accomplish this task, override the `dxet:SearchControlThemeKey ResourceKey=Template` template as it demonstrated in the [following](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q576712) DevExpress Support Center thread. The [example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/78791da1-a54e-11e3-bf1a-f07bcbe8e73a) attached to this thread demonstrates this approach.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm bit stupid. I saw this approach before and didn't understand how to apply this to my example. Can you give me more instructions? Anyhow, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

1) Create a custom localizer class to override PopulateStringTable() to add your string.

```
public class CustomDXGridLocalizer : EditorLocalizer
{
    protected override void PopulateStringTable()
    {
        base.PopulateStringTable();
        AddString(EditorStringId.LookUpSearch, "Your Text");
    }
}
```

2) Add the following to the constructor of your usercontrol or window where you're using the grid.

EditorLocalizer.Active = new CustomDXGridLocalizer();